# Proof that obtuse angles = 90 degrees

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There's a proof on how every obtuse angle is equal to 90 degrees, and I can't seem to find the issue.

> Given: Quadrilateral ABCD, AD=BC, ∠ADB is obtuse, m∠CBD=90
>
> ---
>
> Drawing perpendicular bisectors MP and NP from lines AB and CD (respectively) that intersect at the point P.
>
> ΔPDA ≅ ΔPBC because of SSS
>
> m∠PDB = m∠PBD because of base angles
>
> m∠ADP = m∠CBP because of CPCTC
>
> m∠ADB = m∠ADP - m∠PDB
>
> m∠CBD = m∠CBP - m∠DBP
>
> m∠ADB = m∠CBD
>
> m∠ADB = 90
>
> (the last few steps might be a little different depending on where point P is.)

Obviously, that's not true. I've already tried different cases, such that P was below, inside, and above the quadrilateral, but I can't seem to find the issue in this proof. I also know that P exists, since AC and BD aren't parallel.

Comment: How did you get this m∠PDB = m∠PBD?

Comment: @eepperly16: PD = PB because a point on a perpendicular bisector is equidistant from the endpoints of the segment, so the triangle made is an isosceles triangle, and then the base angles theorem.

Comment: Psych. Drew my picture wrong. My apologies.

Comment: Because AC and BD aren't parallel, so their perpendicular bisectors aren't parallel, and therefore the bisectors intersect. @fleablood

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have *both*:

```
m∠CBD = m∠CBP - m∠DBP
m∠CBD = m∠CBP - m∠DBP
```

Depending on the location of $P$, on will be `+` and the other `-`.

Comment: Of course.... But for when P is inside the quadrilateral, then the angles on both sides add up together to 90.

Comment: Why do you assume point P will ever be inside the quadrilateral?  Why do you assume the perpendicular bisectors aren't parallel?

Comment: @fleablood: Well, since the shape looks kind of like this (but with a line on top and the right side a lot longer) when drawn to scale:  \ __|  then the perpendicular bisectors have to intersect in the center, or above the quadrilateral. I included underneath it since that was how I first came across the proof.

Comment: If P is  between the extended lines AD and CB this will be the proof holds (so I assume this never happens.)  If P is  below both AD and CB the the statements hold for the angles involving CB but not for the angles involving A and D.

Comment: Sorry, just realized something major. I typed the proof wrong. Should be fine now, though. @fleablood

Answer (score 0):

"ΔPDA ≅ ΔPBC because of SSS"

No.  ΔPDA ≅ ΔPCB because PD = PC (not PB) and PA = PB (not PC)

So you have the corresponding angles flipped.

"m∠PDB = m∠PBD because of base angles"

So No. "m∠PDC = m∠PCD" and so on.  The whole thing falls apart.

(I got confused because I drew the picture of the quad as ADBC rather than ABCD and I drew the perpendiculars of  DB and AC, rather than of AB and DC.)

Draw the picture carefully and label the points correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry. While typing this proof, I'm finding that I'm writing down the wrong letters each time. Maybe later, when I have more reputation, I'll post a picture and include a handwritten proof, which will be correct. Again, very sorry.